# prove that the number $n^2 + n + 1$, for natural number $n$ cannot be written as product of numbers whose difference is less than $2 \sqrt{n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

The question is equivalent to number $n^2 + n + 1$ does not have a divisor less than $\sqrt{n^2 + n + 1}$ and greater than $n - \sqrt{n} + 1$, that's all i've got

Comment: Just to say, the bound (if it is true) is sharp...$a_{49}=2451=43\times 57$ and $57-43=14=2\sqrt{49}$.  What is the source of this problem?

Comment: @lulu some old TST preparations

Comment: Best I can see at the moment is to look at:  $n^2+n+1=(n+1)^2-n=(n+1-\sqrt n)(n+1+\sqrt n)$.  No point looking for two factors inside that band...the product would be greater.  Of course, a prioi one factor could be in the band, the other out...so this is not complete (but it feels close).

Comment: @lulu not just $a_{49}$. The bound is sharp with $a_{m^2}$ for all $m$; e.g. $a_4=21=7×3$ gives factors differing by $2\sqrt4$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi  Yeah, meant to point out that that follows from the factoring I gave (when $\sqrt n\in \mathbb N$).

Answer (score 4):

Since $n^2+n+1$ is odd, any two factors having that as a product must both be odd themselves. Thus the difference between the factors is even and we may render

$n^2+n+1=(m+k)(m-k)=m^2-k^2.$

Then $m^2\ge(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1$, this being the next larger square after $n^2+n+1$, forcing $k^2\ge n$ and thus the difference between the factors to satisfy $2k\ge2\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers such that $a \geq b$ and
$$
ab = n^2 + n + 1.
$$
Define
$$
c=\frac{a+b}2 \quad \text{and} \quad d = \frac{a-b}2,
$$
then $c,d$ are non-negative integral multiples of $\frac 1 2,$ and
$$
c^2 - d^2 = (c+d)(c-d) = ab = n^2 + n + 1.
$$
Since $2d = a-b,$ it is sufficient to show that if $c$ and $d$ satisfy the above properties then $d \geq \sqrt n.$

First, we have
$$
c^2 \geq c^2 - d^2 = n^2 + n + 1 > n^2,
$$
or $c>n.$ Second, if $c \geq n + 1,$ then
$$
d^2 = c^2 - (n^2 + n + 1) \geq (n+1)^2 - (n^2 + n + 1) = n,
$$
which implies $d \geq \sqrt n.$ The final case is $c = n + \frac 1 2,$ where
$$
d^2 = \left(n + \frac 1 2 \right)^2 - (n^2 + n + 1) = -\frac 3 4,
$$
which is impossible. (**Edit**: I realized the first inequality is a bit redundant since this already forces $c > n + \frac 1 2.$)